# How to debug JavaScript code called from Java (via JSR-223)?

Tags: java, javascript, debugging, jsr223

I'm developing a java application where some logic is performed via ***jsr223*** (javascript). In java class I forward some java object to javascript (e.g. my domain objects, PreparedStatement for some SQL queries) and then I start compiled javascript code.

I use Eclipse for development.

My question is, how to debug javascript part?

Cheers, Jacek

Comment: Well, for starters there's `println()` in JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy #1 Since when..? and #2 That's *not* debugging :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's info for [debugging js in jsr223 from Netbeans](http://markmail.org/message/usjkgrn45ezvkluq).

Can't say anything about eclipse.